# Change the color of a button using Jquery Ajax (Color received from external PHP file)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

This is my HTML code

```
<form class="addtowatchlistform" action="logo/insertwatchlist.php" method="POST">

    <input type="hidden" name="tmdb_id" value="'.$result[$x]["tmdb_id"].'"/>
    <button id="addtowatchlistbutton" type="submit" name="tmdb_id" value="'.$result[$x]["tmdb_id"].'" data-tooltip="'.$addremove.' TO YOUR WATCHLIST" class="material-icons" style="color:'.$watchlisticoncolor.'">add_box</button>

</form>

   // Same form as above
<form class="addtowatchlistform" action="logo/insertwatchlist.php" method="POST">

    <input type="hidden" name="tmdb_id" value="'.$result[$x]["tmdb_id"].'"/>
    <button id="addtowatchlistbutton" type="submit" name="tmdb_id" value="'.$result[$x]["tmdb_id"].'" data-tooltip="'.$addremove.' TO YOUR WATCHLIST" class="material-icons" style="color:'.$watchlisticoncolor.'">add_box</button>

</form>
```

Jquery Code:

```
<script>
$(".addtowatchlistform").submit(function(e) {
  var data = $(this).serialize();
  var url = $(this).attr("action");
  $.post(url, data, function() {
    try {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        $("button#addtowatchlistbutton").css('color',data.watchlisticoncolor);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("json encoding failed");
        return false;
    }
});
  return false;
});
</script>
```

PHP file `insertwatchlist.php` file

```
$response = new \stdClass();
$response->watchlisticoncolor = "red";
die(json_encode($response));
```

Output of PHP file `insertwatchlist.php` file

```
{"watchlisticoncolor":"red"}
```

**Expected Result:**

1.)When someone clicks on `add_box` button, it submits the form without reloading the page (This one works fine)

2.) `insertwatchlist.php` sends this code: `{"watchlisticoncolor":"red"}` and, the Jquery code place them in place of: `$watchlisticoncolor` variable, in the real time without reloading the page. (This one do not work),

Console tab do not show anything. Here is the screenshot of network tab, when someone clicks on the button http://prntscr.com/fxwt16

Comment: try my answer below. Hope it will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this you have to catch data return from your ajax request in function params

```
<script>
$(".addtowatchlistform").submit(function(e) {
  var data = $(this).serialize();
  var url = $(this).attr("action");
  var form = $(this); // Add this line
  $.post(url, data, function(data) { //<---------add data here
    try {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        $(form).children("button").css('color',data.watchlisticoncolor); //Update this line
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("json encoding failed");
        return false;
    }
});
  return false;
});
</script>
```

Comment: Works but it change the color of all buttons, instead of just the clicked one. Do you know the solution sir?

Comment: if it works, you must select correct button try `$(".addtowatchlistform 
 button#addtowatchlistbutton").css('color',data.watchlisticoncolor);`

Comment: @azad it redirects me to `insertwatchlist.php` file

Answer (score 1):

Please use `background-color` instead of `color`. `color` property will be used when you want to change color of fonts.

**FROM**

```
$("button#addtowatchlistbutton").css('color',data.watchlisticoncolor);
```

**TO**

```
$("button#addtowatchlistbutton").css('background-color',data.watchlisticoncolor);
```

also add data in your ajax function.

```
$.post(url, data, function(data) {
```

Let me know if it not works.

```js
$(".addtowatchlistform").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var data = $(this).serialize();
  var url = $(this).attr("action");
  $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: 'post',
      dataType: 'json',
      beforeSend: function() {
        $('#add_to_wishlist').css('color','red');
      },
      success: function(data) {
      }   
   });
});

$('#add_to_wishlist2').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).css('background-color','red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add_to_wishlist" style="color:yellow;">Change Color</button>


<button id="add_to_wishlist2">Change Background Color</button>
```

Comment: This is a font bro

Comment: So you want to change background-color or color?

Comment: I want to change color bro

Comment: This code is not receiving data from `insertwatchlist.php` file bro

Comment: Please check my updated answer, and change your ajax post call accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Updated:

On further checking I found its not the css proper. Its your jquery post function problem.

You are missing data in the function. Use below; Let me know if it fix your issue.

```
 $.post(url, data, function(data) {
    try {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        $("button#addtowatchlistbutton").css('color',data.watchlisticoncolor);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("json encoding failed");
        return false;
    }
```

---

color property used for text color.
Use background-color instead of color

For Background Color

```
 $("button#addtowatchlistbutton").css('background-color',data.watchlisticoncolor);
```

For Text Color

```
$("button#addtowatchlistbutton").css('color',data.watchlisticoncolor);
```

Comment: This is a font bro

Comment: @Toby do a console log to check if data.watchlisticoncolor is returning correctly.

Comment: Console tab is empty

Comment: Works but it change the color of all buttons, instead of just the clicked one. Do you know the solution sir?

Comment: You must vote up the answer. Otherwise all my efforts are wasted